# Show system file type icons in html page

Tags: javascript, html, icons, file-type

I have a web site which display a directory structure in the back end server. There are lot of file types (extensions) in that directories. I need to display icons for each files. The pretty way is showing relevant icons according to the file extension.

Is there any method to show system file type icons in web browser using html instead of using set of png images for each type?

Comment: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: try this http://fontello.com/

Comment: These are custom icons, aren't they? I need to display the same icon use in Windows explorer in windows and the relevant in different OS platforms.

Comment: no news on this front ? since we can use system fonts, why not system icons ? (apparently only apple allows it through javascript & the UIImage API)